# How to move labels in a JPanel java swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have a panel, and I am trying to have a background image, and two sets of text, a "title" and text area to add text to later
how do I get the text area to go on top of the image (label) or if there is a completely better way to achieve this?

`    //For Text (right)

```
    JPanel textPanel = new JPanel();
    //textPanel.setLayout(); //I don't understand layouts I tried some non really got what I needed
    textPanel.setBorder(border);
    textPanel.setBounds(190, 0, 1300, 886);
    textPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    
//Imports For inventory Label
    JLabel textLabel = new JLabel(); //Title label
    arrayTXTA = new JTextArea(0,1);//The text I will add later label
    JLabel textLabelbg = new JLabel(); //Background image label
    ImageIcon Teximage =new ImageIcon("src\\emporium\\pkg\\background.jpg");//sets up image for background      
//Code for background image
    textLabelbg.setIcon(Teximage);//adds an image
    textLabelbg.setBounds(70, 5, 1200, 886);
                //TEXT AT 253
//Code for title
    textLabel.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);  icon
    textLabel.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.TOP);
    textLabel.setForeground(new Color(0,255,0));
    textLabel.setFont(new Font("Blackadder ITC",Font.BOLD,30));
    //textLabel.setBounds(300, 0, 100, 36);
//Code for Text I will add later
    arrayTXTA.setVisible(true);
    arrayTXTA.append("Words");
    arrayTXTA.append("Words");
    arrayTXTA.append("Words");
    arrayTXTA.setForeground(new Color(255,0,0));
    arrayTXTA.setFont(new Font("Blackadder ITC",Font.BOLD,30));
    arrayTXTA.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
    arrayTXTA.setBounds(25, 0, 0, 0);
    `
```

[Here is a picture of what I am trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cX7RZ.jpg)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

## Firstly

Don't use `null` layouts, they aren't helping you.  Take the time to learn and use the available layout managers, see [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details.

## Secondly

`JLabel` is a bad choice for trying to make background image.  There's a few reasons, but lets just say they aren't really designed for the job

## Thirdly

Start with a custom component and paint the background you want via it.  Use it as the primary container for the `JTextArea`.

Configure the `JScrollPane` and `JTextArea` to be transparent and you will see the background through it

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                    frame.add(new TestPane());
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage background;

        public TestPane() throws IOException {
            background = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/images/Paper.png"));
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            JTextArea ta = new JTextArea("This is some text");
            ta.setOpaque(false);

            JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(ta);
            sp.setOpaque(false);
            sp.getViewport().setOpaque(false);

            add(sp);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(background.getWidth(), background.getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.drawImage(background, 0, 0, this);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }
}
```

As to the rest of you layout.  Simple, make use of a number of containers/panels with their own layout managers and then bind the all together into a "master" panel with a suitable layout manager (`BorderLayout` looks like it would work)

## After thoughts...

Depending on your needs, I might consider having some more logic in the `paintComponent` method to allow it paint more instances of the background if the container was resized beyond the size of the base background image, but that would depend on the image and your needs.

While more difficult, you could look at painting the background directly to the `JTextArea` (by overriding it), this would allow the background to scroll with the `JTextArea`, but would also require you to consider the point above

Comment: I tried changing my code around, and when I add a layout to my panel that holds my text area I lose the title and the text area, if I setVisible to true for the label that is supposed to be the background picture I see the picture still which is confusing.
I also tried adding your changes, but I get an error with "paintComponent" but "paintComponets" works with no error besides the @override part needs to be deleted and I get an error at getViewport() if I get rid of getting viewpoint I get an error at background=ImageIO..
I am sorry I just way to new to swing to understand why I have errors

Comment: 1. If you're "losing" components because the layout manager, then you're not using it right; 2. `paintComponets` is the wrong method.  If you're getting an error on `@override` then you're extending from the wrong component;  The example I have provided works (you need to supply your own image)

Comment: 1. Yeah, I need to learn layout manager, I am doing this as "extra credit" for a beginner java class so I was trying to avoid diving too deep into swing, but oh well. I got layouts working on a basic login screen as a test! but when I say losing, I think it's getting lost behind the other panel. but doesn't matter I need to learn more
2. I might be getting an error because I don't have my code broken up as you do, I have a "Myframe class" and 2 panels and buttons running down the whole thing lol. I still am not sure about the background painting but that I can try it again on.

Comment: Start from a base of working and then wrap you ideas around it.  For me, I'd use a `BorderLayout` and place the text area (or the panel that's used to provide the background) in the centre and use the `NORTH` position of the rest

Comment: Wow, it's been 10 days since I worked on this huh, I figured it out the back way, I guess I didn't realize but I had the "background-image" above the Jlabel and Jtextarea
it works, probably not as cleanly as your fix did. but what are you gonna do? lol I think I am gonna switch this to C++ anyway for my next class as my final project so I am not going to put too much work into this, gonna get the extra credit for my "advanced code" in my beginner level java class and run lol

Thank you so much for your time though I really appreciated it, and realized how messy my code was lol